# Using Python: Group by and plot ratios to compare them, add aditional calculations (ie: histogram, scatter plot, density plot)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Measuring sales with ratios and plot them.

The following data is about 4 salespeople.
The salespeople always work in pairs.
There are 3 data sets for each pair of salespeople; 12 likely combinations of the salespeople, so 36 rows of data.
One salesperson is seated at a desk and the other person is standing, both are talking to clients, s1 = salesman # 1, s2 = salesman # 2, s3 = salesman # 3, s4 = salesman # 4.

There are 12 combinations where each of the salespeople are seated or standing at different times. There are 36 data points.

In a plot, I want to show how far the Ratio Standing / Seated is compared with the Ratio Target, then add the # of minutes working (using bars maybe). In the end, I want to have 3 ratios of standing/seated and I want to see how far they are compared with the ratio target. I should have 12 plots because there are 12 different pairs.

I have tried this in Python with Groupby (Pandas) but I cannot plot any of that

At this point I am not sure if I should continue using "groupby". I want to plot each equal pair (ie. s1, s2) showing the standing/seated ratio with 1 color and the ratio target with a different color. I am not sure if I should use a Scatter Plot, Density, or other.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
OB = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\isaac\\Example_datav2.xlsx')
OB.shape
OB2 = OB.groupby(['seated','standing'])
OB2.describe
```

Data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K06PGtZk5CeGJTCoLmLZpSWMHXLgovfBUHvsfKhuWCQ/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use e.g. OB2.describe(include='all') - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html for your calculation. OB.groupby is used correctly. You may also use DataFrame.reindex, if required.